# PHP POST request script working when run from command line but not from browser

Tags: php, nginx, curl, post, https

I have a PHP script that posts data to another server. It works when I run the script from the command line, but when I run it from a browser I get HTTP code 0 and `curl_error()` is an empty string. What could cause this?

Both servers are on AWS running CentOS Stream 9 and Nginx.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'name' => "jack",
    'email' => "jack@example.com"
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.com/register.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($res === false) {
    echo "<p>curl_error: ".curl_error($ch)."</p>\n";
}

echo stripslashes($res);
echo "\n<p>http code: ".$httpCode."</p>\n";

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us what error you are getting there

Comment: I didn't get any - `curl_error($ch)` returns an empty string

Comment: Can you check whether your api is working properly with 200 status. If yes than there might be issue with POST data are you posting any Special Characters in your array?

Comment: "from command line"...command line on the server, or on your local machine? Maybe the server blocks outbound connections, for example.

Comment: It works from the command line on the server, it returns status code 200. I also ran it as the nginx user and it worked. There are no special characters.

Comment: Can you try like this ``` $curl = curl_init($url);``` and your post data with ```http_build_query($data)```

Comment: Tried it, it didn't change anything

Comment: Did you tried with curl_init($url) instead of CURLOPT_URL

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'name' => "jack",
    'email' => "jack@example.com"
);

$ch = curl_init('https://www.example.com/register.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($res === false) {
    echo "<p>curl_error: ".curl_error($ch)."</p>\n";
}

echo stripslashes($res);
echo "\n<p>http code: ".$httpCode."</p>\n";

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I think it should properly.

Comment: It's great if you have a solution but you should, for the benefit of everyone, explain _why_ you think it will solve the problem

Comment: I tried it like this, the output is the same.

Comment: ``` CURLOPT_URL ``` doesn't works that why you have to make a curl call like this but can you please say us what error are you getting.